# MediaRecorder start error codes

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I want to record raw h.264 video without sound and possibly HW accelerated (and stream it later). So I decided to use `MediaRecorder` (and the socket *hack* for streaming).

I have the following code:

```
final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
final Camera camera = Camera.open();
camera.unlock();
recorder.setCamera(camera);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
final CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
recorder.setVideoSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);
recorder.setVideoFrameRate(profile.videoFrameRate);
recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate);
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

And bam! This in logcat:

```
E/MediaRecorder﹕ start failed: -38
```

I started googling, and found plenty of questions and answers, but none about my error code `-38`.

So I tried to look at Android [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/MediaRecorder.java#758), and noticed it's `native` method, and I don't know where to look for that.

So my big question is: **Is there some list of those error codes, so I could find what error `-38` means?`**

Also know tjat I'm targeting API 10 (Gingerbread) and building with latest SDK 21.

Comment: It doesn't really mean anything, unfortunately. Somewhere several layers down there may be a useful error code, but by the time it bubbles its way out to the app it's pretty much always -38. You may be able to find some useful information by looking back a bit in the logcat output for other errors or warnings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, I think I have an answer for you. The start function that is failing is defined in a file called `mediarecorder.cpp`. Found here:

```
frameworks/av/media/libmedia/mediarecorder.cpp
```

This start function returns a variable of type `status_t`, and corresponds to the error that you're seeing thrown.

Now, the type `status_t` is defined in a file called `Errors.h` which can be found here:

```
system/core/include/utils/Errors.h
```

This defines an enumeration that corresponds to `status_t` as seen here:

```
enum {
    OK                = 0,    // Everything's swell.
    NO_ERROR          = 0,    // No errors.

    UNKNOWN_ERROR       = 0x80000000,

    NO_MEMORY           = -ENOMEM,
    INVALID_OPERATION   = -ENOSYS,
    BAD_VALUE           = -EINVAL,
    BAD_TYPE            = 0x80000001,
    NAME_NOT_FOUND      = -ENOENT,
    PERMISSION_DENIED   = -EPERM,
    NO_INIT             = -ENODEV,
    ALREADY_EXISTS      = -EEXIST,
    DEAD_OBJECT         = -EPIPE,
    FAILED_TRANSACTION  = 0x80000002,
    JPARKS_BROKE_IT     = -EPIPE,
#if !defined(HAVE_MS_C_RUNTIME)
    BAD_INDEX           = -EOVERFLOW,
    NOT_ENOUGH_DATA     = -ENODATA,
    WOULD_BLOCK         = -EWOULDBLOCK, 
    TIMED_OUT           = -ETIMEDOUT,
    UNKNOWN_TRANSACTION = -EBADMSG,
#else    
    BAD_INDEX           = -E2BIG,
    NOT_ENOUGH_DATA     = 0x80000003,
    WOULD_BLOCK         = 0x80000004,
    TIMED_OUT           = 0x80000005,
    UNKNOWN_TRANSACTION = 0x80000006,
#endif    
    FDS_NOT_ALLOWED     = 0x80000007,
};
```

As you can see, some of the values here are taken from `errno.h`, so we just need to see which one equates to a value of 38.

According to [this source](http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno), 38 corresponds to `ENOSYS`. So, if we look back at the status_t enumeration, we can see that in android, `ENOSYS` corresponds to an invalid operation. Not terribly helpful, but  I hope this at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: #define ENOSYS      38  /* Function not implemented */

Comment: How was this resolved then? I'm stuck with the same error here.

Answer (score 1):

I have meet this error code in my call recorder app.
this error code will show in logcat when you start media recorder while the **`Microphone is in use`** in another app like a Voice Assistant (for example: Ok google, etc) or another call recorder application.