# takePicture failed, error=-38

Tags: android, android-camera

I noticed in my crash reporter I had several crashes on some devices with stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed, error=-38
   at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Camera.java)
   at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1728)
   at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1661)
```

I know this is a common error and it can have many causes but it's one of the first time I have an error number. Where can I find a list of these error numbers and their meaning?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

There can be many reasons for this in my case i was trying to take photo without preview (hidden photo) and i was using `SurfaceView`, So i replaced it with

```
SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(10);
camera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
```

and the problem was solved... 
P.S I was getting this error only on Above 6.0 devices

Comment: where did you make that replacement exactly?

Comment: `SurfaceView` to `SurfaceTexture`

Answer (score 0):

I just found a list of errors in the file `Camera.java`:

```
private static final int NO_ERROR = 0;
private static final int EACCESS = -13;
private static final int ENODEV = -19;
private static final int EBUSY = -16;
private static final int EINVAL = -22;
private static final int ENOSYS = -38;
private static final int EUSERS = -87;
private static final int EOPNOTSUPP = -95;
```

This post is also related to my question: [MediaRecorder start error codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610058/mediarecorder-start-error-codes)

Not very useful though..