# Record from MIC and stream to TCP server; MediaRecorder: start failed: -38

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, audio-streaming

I am trying to stream audio from the microphone of an Android device to a server over TCP. Problem is that I get an error on the console. The TCP connection is made but no audio data is sent.

I realize it could be because of a bad choice of codec because some needs to be able to seek in the stream which is not possible. I can actually use any codec that works but I read that MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR and MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB was the best combination for streaming. Please suggest another alternative if there is a better one.

Here is what I see in the log:

```
11-06 11:09:27.276 22983-22983/se.jensolsson.test.test D/ViewRootImpl@5ed8717[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
11-06 11:09:27.355 22983-22983/se.jensolsson.test.test D/ViewRootImpl@5ed8717[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
11-06 11:09:27.387 22983-25466/se.jensolsson.test.test I/MediaRecorderJNI: setup
11-06 11:09:27.394 22983-25466/se.jensolsson.test.test I/MediaRecorderJNI: setAudioSource(1)
11-06 11:09:27.397 22983-25466/se.jensolsson.test.test I/MediaRecorderJNI: setAudioEncoder(1)
11-06 11:09:27.400 22983-25466/se.jensolsson.test.test I/MediaRecorderJNI: setOutputFile
11-06 11:09:27.400 22983-25466/se.jensolsson.test.test I/MediaRecorderJNI: prepare
11-06 11:09:27.407 22983-25466/se.jensolsson.test.test I/MediaRecorderJNI: start
11-06 11:09:27.408 22983-25466/se.jensolsson.test.test E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -38
11-06 11:09:27.408 22983-25466/se.jensolsson.test.test W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException
11-06 11:09:27.411 22983-25466/se.jensolsson.test.test W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaRecorder._start(Native Method)
11-06 11:09:27.411 22983-25466/se.jensolsson.test.test W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(MediaRecorder.java:1170)
11-06 11:09:27.411 22983-25466/se.jensolsson.test.test W/System.err:     at se.jensolsson.test.test.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:78)
11-06 11:09:27.411 22983-25466/se.jensolsson.test.test W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Here are the relevant parts of the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here is the source code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    private boolean permissionToRecordAccepted;
    private static final int REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION = 200;

    private ParcelFileDescriptor pfd;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION:
                permissionToRecordAccepted  = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                if (!permissionToRecordAccepted ) finish();
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO }, REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);

        Button buttonStartRecording = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_start_recording);
        buttonStartRecording.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Socket s = new Socket("10.0.83.8", 8888);
                            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(s);

                            MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR);
                            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                            recorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor());

                            try {
                                recorder.prepare();
                            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            recorder.start();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

            }
        });   
    }
}
```

The device I am running on is a Samsung Galaxy A5 with Android 7.0. I am using minSdkVersion 22 and targetSdkVersion 26 in the gradle file.

**EDIT: The preinstalled app Voice recorder works fine. So I dont see how this could be that the microphone is busy.**

**EDIT 2: If I change to the following and save to a file instead of a stream, it seem to work. So I still bet there is a problem with the sound format and streaming as a network stream does not support seek. If this is the case, what format should I use??**

```
//recorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
File outputFile = File.createTempFile("test", "mp4", getApplicationContext().getCacheDir());
recorder.setOutputFile(outputFile.getPath());
```

**EDIT 3**
None of the answers are correct. I have now found out that the main problem is that I cannot save the sound data to a stream created by ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket

It works however if I do this

```
ParcelFileDescriptor[] mParcelFileDescriptors = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();
final ParcelFileDescriptor mParcelRead = new ParcelFileDescriptor(mParcelFileDescriptors[0]);
ParcelFileDescriptor mParcelWrite = new ParcelFileDescriptor(mParcelFileDescriptors[1]);
```

And then send the stream contents to a server.
I do not know if there is some timing issue with this or if it could cause corruption for certain sound file formats as I guess bytes in the header could change at any time depending on format.

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer it is because the mic is in use by another application, voice assistant included https://stackoverflow.com/a/47290248/3938238

Comment: So i need to turn off voice assistant to be able to record? I tried recording using the built in sound recorder and that worked fine. Is there any way to make this work more smooth?

Comment: Does not seem to be voice assistant.It is set to the off position in settings.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps that's because there is some other app that is using phone's mic , please see :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23975085/5479863

Comment: Maybe, but which app? This is a brand new phone without anything specific installed to it. I now also tried on Galaxy S5 Neo. Same problem